# Insert one file's content into another file and replace it between pattern

Tags: shell, sed, replace, html

I have a **file1.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    text
    <!-- start-replacing -->
<p>more text1</p>
<p>more text2</p>
    <!-- end-replacing -->
    other text
</body>
</html>
```

and a **file2.txt**

```
<p>some text</p>
<div>some other text</div>
```

Now I'm looking for a command to replace everything between

`<!-- start-replacing -->` and `<!-- end-replacing -->`

with the content of file2.txt

the **output.html** should be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    text
    <!-- start-replacing -->
<p>some text</p>
<div>some other text</div>
    <!-- end-replacing -->
    other text
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Parsing or modifying HTML (or any other kind of structured text such as XML or JSON) with regular expressions alone is extremely fragile, at best. Even tiny changes to the expected input will break your script. You should use a language with an HTML or XML parsing library - e.g. perl's [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Parser) is one of several perl libraries that parses HTML into a perl object you can interact with as you would any other data object.  Python and Java and C and many other languages have similar libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  BEGIN{$repl = <STDIN>}
  s/<!-- start-replacing -->\K.*?(?=<!-- end-replacing -->)/$repl/sg
' file1.html < file2.txt > output.html
```

Comment: Or use `-g` instead of `-0777` beginning with Perl 5.36

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed`:

```bash
sed -e '/<!-- end-replacing -->/e cat file2.txt' -e '/<!-- start-replacing -->/,//{//!d}' file1.html
```

The `e` command is used to call the external command `cat file2.txt` on the ending address range. The file contents will be inserted before the matching line.

The lines between the address range is then deleted. `//` represents the last used regex (the ending range after the comma and both the addresses within the `{}` block).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ee '/start-replacing/{{r file2.txt' -e '};n;:a;N;s/.*\n(.*end-replacing[^\n]*\n)/\1/;ba}' file1.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    text
    <!-- start-replacing -->
<p>some text</p>
<div>some other text</div>
    <!-- end-replacing -->
    other text
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

W3C's [`HTML-XML-utils`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/)
are HTML-aware and / or XML-aware.
The [`hxincl`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxincl.html)
utility from the `html-xml-utils` package expands certain embedded
comments or prints a `makefile` rule listing the dependent include files.

```sh
hxincl -s incfnm='file2.txt' file1.html
```

generates the desired output given a slightly modified input:

```html
    <!-- begin-include "incfnm" -->

<p>more text1</p>
<p>more text2</p>
    <!-- end-include "incfnm" -->
```